Generation of Password Element IEEE std. 802.11 in Python
I'm trying to implement the generation of Password Element for WPA3 SAE in Python according to IEEE standard 802.11.
In the Appendix, I found the SAE test vectors, however I have a problem in the KDF function.
My KDF function is:
import hmac
import hashlib
from math import ceil

def kdf(k: bytes):
    """
    KDF-SHA-256-256
    :k: password-seed (H[max(mac_a, mac_b) || min(mac_a, mac_b), password || counter])
    :label: ASCII string indetifying the purpose of the keys derived.
    :context: bit string that provides context to identify the derived key
    :return: A length-bit derived key
    """
    label = b"SAE Hunting and Pecking"
    context = 0xFFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF # Prime number for DH Group 19
    length = 256 # Length of the derived key in bits
    hash_len = 32 * 8 # Length of the digest produced by hash function (in bits)
    iterations = ceil(length / hash_len)
    result = b""
    for i in range(1, iterations + 1):
        data = i.to_bytes(2, "big") + label + context + length.to_bytes(2, "big")
        result = result + H(key=k, data=data)
    return result[:length]


def H(key: bytes, data: bytes):
    """
    :data: message to use
    :key: key to use
    """
    return hmac.new(key, data, hashlib.sha256).digest()

And the first vectors of the IEEE std.:
group: 19
Password: ‘thisisreallysecret’
Local MAC address: 7b-88-56-20-2d-8d
Peer’s MAC address: e2-47-1c-0a-5a-cb
H(e2-47-1c-0a-5a-cb || 7b-88-56-20-2d-8d, thisisreallysecret || 1)
69f69099 83675392 d0a3a882 47ffef20 413ee972 15872942 4415e139 46ecc206
candidate x value:
a16729e0 339c38f8 b06e2b83 76d43066 85578354 ab09d848 a0f140ac 825e6a3d

I have the correct output for H, but for x value (which should be the output of KDF function) I have something different.
Any thoughts of my errors ?
